# invalid literal for int() with base 10: while trying to create a dataframe with split '_'

Tags: python, regex, for-loop, lambda, split

I am trying to add a column to an existing dataframe by splitting different parts of file name with special character underscore '_'.

Below is the screenshot of my dataframe.

[image]

Now I would like to have **another column added to the existing dataframe that has values after '_' and before .jpg like 1 in row1 and 10 in row2.**

Below is the code I am using, but I am getting the error **invalid literal for int() with base 10: combined**

```
master_df = pd.DataFrame()
master_df['filename'] = combined_faces_image_names
master_df['age'] = master_df['filename'].map(lambda img_name : np.uint8(img_name.split("_")[0]))
```

Could someone please help me?

Comment: What is the expected result for `combined_faces.zip`? Or `100_a.png` ?

Answer (score 1):

The error actually tells you, that the word `combined` in your 33486 row that comes after splitting `combined_faces.zip` cannot be converted to int.

Try to remove this row from the DataFrame and then do the conversion and splitting, or locate only rows containing `.jpg` rows for that purpose:

```
master_df['age'] = master_df['filename'].map(lambda img_name: np.uint8(img_name.split("_")[0]) if '.jpg' in img_name else None)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use [`pandas.Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for this task, minifed example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['100_1.jpg','100_10.jpg','combined_faces.zip']})
df['value'] = df['name'].str.extract(r'(\d+).jpg$')
```

print(df)

```
output
                 name value
0           100_1.jpg     1
1          100_10.jpg    10
2  combined_faces.zip   NaN
```

Explanation: extract one or more (`+`) digits (`\d`) followed by `.jpg` and end of string (`$`). Note that in above example value (where not `NaN`) are `str`s. If you need numbers, you might use [`pandas.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) as follows

```
df['value'] = pd.to_numeric(df['name'].str.extract(r'(\d+).jpg$',expand=False))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a try and except approach for the extraction
I'd also probably just loop through the first column for this matter

```
import pandas as pd

master_df = pd.DataFrame()
master_df['filename'] = combined_faces_image_names

extract = []
for i in master_df['filename']:
    offset = i.index("_")
    num = i[offset+1:-4]
    # -4 to leave out the .jpg
    try:
        extract.append(int(num))
    except ValueError:
        extract.append("")

master_df['Age'] = extract
```